# Current Working Directory for Header Files C++

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am in the process of compilation and I am having problems with the path to custom header files.

Here is the structure of the repository.

```
temp
  seqLib
  headerFiles
    SeqLibCommon.h
  src
    hello_world.cpp
```

In the **hello_world.cpp** file is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "../headerFiles/SeqLibCommon.h"
```

This compiles and works but, in C++ packages, the path to SeqLibCommon.h would be referenced as such:

```
#include "headerFiles/SeqLibCommon.h"
```

Why are the two different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An R package compilation is always relative to `src/` which becomes the working directory for the build.

If you want to add that directory *explicitly* you can add

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I.
```

And if you want to add the directory `inst/include/` you would have to add

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I../inst/include
```

as you need to be *relative* to `src/`.  You can combine both.

As for your SeqLib sources: you can move things around, or adjust your `src/Makevars` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Every common compiler allow you to define an include folder. Here you can say that `headerFiles` is your include folder, so your hello_world would be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "SeqLibCommon.h"
```

Or you can define your include folder as temp so it would be

```
#include "headerFiles/SeqLibCommon.h"
```

On g++ or clang, you can compile like that:

```
g++ src/hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -I headerFiles
```